# bower dump current components (like pip freeze for python)

Tags: node.js, package, bower

Python Package Index (pip) has `pip freeze` command which dumps a `requirements.txt` file that states everything which is installed in current (virtual) environment. Does node's bower has a similar command? Say, I've run several `bower install <component-x>` and I don't want to bother about names and versions of the vendors - can bower generate bower.json for me, basing on what is included in local `bower_components` directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm, didn't realize that `bower init` does the job when some `bower_components` dependencies are already there...